# Get data out of a webpage with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get some data out of this Webpage:

http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphone-tarife.html

I want to have the whole table on the right site for every Smartphone and every contract type.

one time payment for Setting up: Anschlusspreis

one time payment for the phone: Smartphone

total amount: Gesamt

Monthly payment for the contract: Basispreis

Monthly payment for the mobile phone: Smartphone-Zuzahlung

This is all stored in the JavaScript part which is a huge amout of letters.

I´m trying to use Excel VBA:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  'On Error GoTo Errorhandler
  Dim ie As Object, doc As Object, rng As Object, ticker As String, quote As String

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  i = 1

  'Application.StatusBar = "Your request is loading. Please wait..."

  ie.navigate "http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphone-tarife.html"
  'ie.navigate ticker

  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  Set doc = ie.document

  quote = doc.getElementsByID("connectionFeeVal").innerText
  Cells(3, 3).Value = quote

  MsgBox ("done")

'Errorhandler:
  'If Err = 91 Then MsgBox "Error Message"

  ie.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

But it is continuously Looping at "DoEvents".

Does someone have an idea why and how I can solve this and maybe another idea how to get all this data out of this page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sometimes the DoEvents has problems.  You can also try these three lines: `Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the IE automation you can also use a http request object:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphone-tarife.html"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

it's faster and doesn't need as many ressources as the solution with the IE

if you are behind a proxy server you can use something like this:

```
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.setProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "http://proxy.intern:8080"
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphone-tarife.html"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

of course you have to adjust the proxy to your values.

As you are interessted in a german page here also a short explanation in german language: http://cboden.de/softwareentwicklung/vba/tipps-tricks/27-webseite-per-vba-ansprechen
There is also explained how to pass values of a form to the webserver which might also be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect it is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Do
    DoEvents

Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

You could try:

```
Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

with ie
...
end with
```