# How to read html code in order to grab data with excel vba

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I'm trying to grab som data from a webpage with Excel VBA.

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="PriceLabel" class="skuPrice formRow">
  <span class="skuPriceWrp">
    <strong class="price red" id="skuPriceLabel" style="font-size: 20px;"> 
       <span class="VAT">eks mva </span><br>
       <span itemprop="price" id="SkuPriceUpdate">kr 
         <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="NOK">151,20</span>
       </span> 
     </strong>
     <span> /
       <span class="UOM" telephone="no">RL
       </span>
     </span>
  </span>
                        <span class="skuUOMWrp">
                            <span id="showEachPrice" class="clear"></span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="formRow clear" id="divSkuSavePrice">
                            <span id="divSkuWhenYouBuy">
                                <span class="whenYouSave"></span>&nbsp;
                            </span>

                        </div>

</div>
```

**What i want to grab is the value `151,20`, located on the first "span".**

I've tried: `.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText`

This gives the value "Eks mva" sometimes, and runtime error 424 (object required) at other times.

I've tried using `.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText` 
and
`.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(2).innerText`
as well, but those give the 424 runtime error.

Can somebody please give show me how to read the html code so i can see the logic and know what to look for and write the next time?

My full code is

```
Sub get_data_2()
'Source for this code is:
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613043/get-data-out-of-a-webpage-with-vba

Dim ie As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SKU As String
Dim RowCount As Long

Set sht = Sheet8
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

RowCount = 1
'This just gives the columns a titel i row numer 1.
sht.Range("a" & RowCount) = "SKU" 'Column A is populated with SKU's to be looked up.
sht.Range("n" & RowCount) = "Price" 'Column N will be given the price of the SKU.


With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.staples.no/"

Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Do
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    SKU = sht.Range("a" & RowCount).Value

    With ie 'fill in the searchbox and submit.
        ie.document.all("searchKeywords").Value = SKU 'we can use 491215 as a SKU for this example.
        ie.document.forms("searchForm").submit

        Do While .Busy Or _
            .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'write the price to column N
        sht.Range("n" & RowCount).Value = ie.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(1).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText

    End With
Loop While sht.Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Value <> "" 'Loop as long as column A has a SKU (till end of list).
End With
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `getElementById("skuPriceLabel")` with  `getElementsByClassName("skuPriceLabel")(0)`

Comment: `.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(1).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText`

Comment: I can't seem to make that work. I assume that `.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText` still follows on the first sugestion. I still get a 424 error. That also applies to the second sugestion.

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise look at my answer below

Comment: Full code listed in updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have 2 options:

### 1. DOM

`.document.getElementById("skuPriceLabel").getElementsByTagName("span")(1).getEl‌​ementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText`

### 2. Regex

Use regex: `content=""NOK"">(.*?)<` with this function

```
Public Function GetRegex(str As String, reg As String, Optional index As Integer) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = reg
    regex.Global = True
    If index < 0 Then index = 0
    If regex.test(str) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
        GetRegex = matches(index).SubMatches(0)
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetRegex = ""
End Function
```